# Receiving Error On 4GB File Size Limit Even With compatibility level of 1100

Tags: ssas, olap, cube

We are currently creating an OLAP cube using a degenerate dimension based upon our fact table to link to another one to many fact table. We have the source database on SQL Server 2012 with compatibility level on it set to `SQL Server 2012 (110)`. We have set the `stringstoragecompatibilitylevel` on this degenerate dimension to `1100` as well. We even went so far as to set all dimensions and cube partitions to use `1100`. Yet, we are still getting the following error:

```
Processing Dimension Attribute 'Data Time Period ID' failed. 155130000 rows have been read.
    Start time: 7/21/2016 9:31:08 AM; End time: 7/22/2016 10:08:00 AM; Duration: 24:36:52
    Error Messages 1
        File system error: A string store or binary store with a compatibility level of '1050'
        is at the maximum file size of 4 gigabytes. To store additional strings, you can change
        the StringStoresCompatibilityLevel property of the associated dimension or distinct count
        measure to '1100' and reprocess. This option is only available on databases with a
        compatibility level of '1100' or higher.
        Physical file: \\?\I:\s2012\OLAP\Data\DATAwarehouse.0.db\DimfactDegenerate.0.dim\18.Data Time Period ID.asstore.
        Logical file: .
        Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the 'Data Time Period ID' attribute
        of the 'DimfactDegenerate' dimension from the 'DATAwarehouse' database was being processed.
```

The target OLAP database, dimensions, cube partitions, and source data warehouse are all set to use `1100`. I have verified the OLAP database/dimensions/partitions are all on `1100` by scripting out the database and searching for the compatibility level. I even searched for `1050` and it does not show in the script.

There are about 900 million records in the fact table. The bridge table contains 1.8 billion records. The total size of just the 2 columns used in the degenerate dimension based on the fact table is about 15 GB (based upon flat file output of just those columns - very back of the envelop). All rows added the degenerate dimension are unique. From reading about how compatibility level should "pass" we are satisfied:

1. Database source is on SQL Server 2012 with compatibility level set.
2. Target OLAP database is using `1100` compatibility
3. Cube partitions are using `1100` compatibility
4. Dimensions are using `1100` compatibility
5. There are under 65 billion records
6. All records are unique

What other options or design changes do I have to get around this seemingly improbable error?

Comment: Hi, I'm facing this issue right now. Can you please let me know, how you resolved this issue?

Comment: @Chandru, I believe my final "solution" was just to re-create the OLAP project from scratch setting everything to 1100 first. Something in the build XMLs was not being updated if I set the compatibility after I did a build/process. Not really the best solution but that is how I got around it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Okay, will try this solution. If you came to know any other different solution, let us know.

Answer (score 0):

For all of you still struggling with this topic:

```
<Alter ObjectExpansion="ExpandFull" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
    <Object>
        <DatabaseID>YourOlapDbNameHere</DatabaseID>
    </Object>
    <ObjectDefinition>
        <Database xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2" xmlns:ddl100_100="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100" xmlns:ddl200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200" xmlns:ddl200_200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200/200" xmlns:ddl300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300" xmlns:ddl300_300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300/300" xmlns:ddl400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400" xmlns:ddl400_400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400/400" xmlns:ddl500="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2013/engine/500" xmlns:ddl500_500="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2013/engine/500/500">
            <ID>YourOlapDbNameHere</ID>
            <Name>YourOlapDbNameHere</Name>
            <ddl200:CompatibilityLevel>1100</ddl200:CompatibilityLevel>
            <Language>1033</Language>
            <Collation>Latin1_General_CI_AS</Collation>
            <DataSourceImpersonationInfo>
                <ImpersonationMode>Default</ImpersonationMode>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must edit the xml configuration file in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS14.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Data and all properties refer to StringStoresCompatibilityLevel set to 11

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after a recent deployment, even though that dimension wasn't modified. We made the change to stringstoragecompatibilitylevel = 1100 and still didn't work.

The solution for us was to *delete* the database and then redeploy from VS and process. Luckily, this was a test environment so no impact to end-users.

Answer (score -1):

after updating stringstoragecompatibilitylevel to 1100 process the dimension in FULL mode - this must fix the error